# Trying to setup Orbeon + Tomcat + MySql with relational database

Tags: mysql, database, tomcat, orbeon, relational

i am having trouble here at my work trying to setup Orbeon to use relational databases running on tomcat and mysql.

So i am an as3 programmer that makes games and doing this is quite difficult for me. 
I've setup Orbeon forms already, i have a mysql server running, now i have to link it to tomcat and orbeon.
(im running ubuntu servere)

I have apache tomcat 7,
orbeon form 4.10 PE .
Mysql (lastest (?)) 
This is my server.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mysql"
 auth="Container"
 type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 initialsize="3"
 driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useUnicode=true&  amp;characterEncoding=UTF8"
 maxActive="15"
 maxIdle="20"
 maxWait="30000"

 username="root"
 password="orbeonadmin2015"

/>
```

my "catalina.out"

```
sep 07, 2015 12:22:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 1780 ms
sep 07, 2015 12:22:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
ADVERTENCIA: maxIdle is larger than maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 15
sep 07, 2015 12:22:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio Catalina
sep 07, 2015 12:22:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
sep 07, 2015 12:22:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMACIÓN: Desplieque del descriptor de configuración /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/examples.xml
sep 07, 2015 12:22:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMACIÓN: Desplieque del descriptor de configuración /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMACIÓN: Desplieque del descriptor de configuración /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMACIÓN: Desplieque del descriptor de configuración /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
sep 07, 2015 12:22:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del archivo /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/orbeon.war de la aplicación web
sep 07, 2015 12:22:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
GRAVE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 32 more

sep 07, 2015 12:22:23 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
ADVERTENCIA: Excepción inesperada resolviendo referencia
java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 32 more

sep 07, 2015 12:22:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
ADVERTENCIA: No pude registrar en JMX: javax.naming.NamingException
Starting Orbeon Forms 4.10.0.201508261723 PE
Initializing Resource Manager with: {oxf.resources.priority.2.oxf.resources.webapp.rootdir=/WEB-INF/resources, org.orbeon.oxf.resources.WebAppResourceManagerImplWebAppContext=org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ServletWebAppContext@2f4be7b5, oxf.resources.factory=org.orbeon.oxf.resources.PriorityResourceManagerFactory, oxf.resources.priority.2=org.orbeon.oxf.resources.WebAppResourceManagerFactory, oxf.resources.priority.4=org.orbeon.oxf.resources.ClassLoaderResourceManagerFactory}
Using run mode: prod
Using properties file: oxf:/config/properties-prod.xml
This installation of Orbeon Forms 4.10.0.201508261723 PE is licensed to: Leandro / MIW / leandrom@makeitwork.com.uy and expires on 2015-12-02
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../logs/orbeon.log (No existe el archivo o el directorio)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:295)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1006)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:887)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:704)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.util.LoggerFactory.initLogger(LoggerFactory.java:95)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.Orbeon$.initialize(Orbeon.scala:81)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonWebApp$$anonfun$1.apply(WebAppContext.scala:117)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonWebApp$$anonfun$1.apply(WebAppContext.scala:117)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:194)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ParametersAndAttributes$$anon$1.getOrElseUpdate(WebAppContext.scala:93)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonWebApp$class.$init$(WebAppContext.scala:117)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ServletWebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.scala:122)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.WebAppContext$.apply(WebAppContext.scala:167)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.pipeline.InitUtils$.runWithServletContext(InitUtils.scala:170)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener$$anonfun$contextInitialized$1.apply$mcV$sp(OrbeonServletContextListener.scala:40)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener$$anonfun$contextInitialized$1.apply(OrbeonServletContextListener.scala:40)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener$$anonfun$contextInitialized$1.apply(OrbeonServletContextListener.scala:40)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.util.ScalaUtils$.withRootException(ScalaUtils.scala:83)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener.contextInitialized(OrbeonServletContextListener.scala:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
sep 07, 2015 12:22:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del directorio /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT de la aplicación web
sep 07, 2015 12:22:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 20949 ms
```

And another log:

```
GRAVE: La aplicación web [/orbeon] parece haber arrancado un hilo llamado [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] pero no ha podido pararlo. Esto tiene todas las papeletas de convertirse en un fallo de memoria.
sep 07, 2015 12:22:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFORMACIÓN: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMACIÓN: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
ADVERTENCIA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
sep 07, 2015 12:22:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 1780 ms
sep 07, 2015 12:22:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
ADVERTENCIA: maxIdle is larger than maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 15
sep 07, 2015 12:22:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio Catalina
sep 07, 2015 12:22:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
sep 07, 2015 12:22:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMACIÓN: Desplieque del descriptor de configuración /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/examples.xml
sep 07, 2015 12:22:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFORMACIÓN: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMACIÓN: Desplieque del descriptor de configuración /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMACIÓN: Desplieque del descriptor de configuración /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml
sep 07, 2015 12:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFORMACIÓN: Desplieque del descriptor de configuración /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
sep 07, 2015 12:22:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del archivo /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/orbeon.war de la aplicación web
sep 07, 2015 12:22:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
GRAVE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 32 more

sep 07, 2015 12:22:23 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
ADVERTENCIA: Excepción inesperada resolviendo referencia
java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
```

Comment: Is the space in the db URL intentional? I see `=true&  amp;`, and it should be `=true&amp;`.

Comment: This helped me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750689/cannot-connect-orbeon-to-my-own-mysql I hope that can help you too!